# Android Notification .addAction function

Tags: android, android-notifications

```
mDatabase.child("reportList").child(i).child("Ambulance_Coming").setValue("Rejected");
```

Above code allows me to make a notification. The problem is, I've added two `.addAction` to my notification. Now when I press the reject button, I just want to do this line

```
   NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(HomeScreenAmbulance.this);
                            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                            builder.setAutoCancel(true);
                            String header = "REPORT RECEIVED:";
                            builder.setContentTitle(header);
                            String body = "Location:"+location;
                            builder.setContentText(body);

                            Intent intent = new Intent("ph.edu.upm.agila.extendthelife.controller.rescuer.ambulance.MainScreenAmbulance");
                            intent.putExtra("FA_id",FA_id);

                            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(HomeScreenAmbulance.this);
                            stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainScreenAmbulance.class);
                            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);

                            PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                            builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Reject",null);
                            builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Accept",pendingIntent);

                            builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
                            NotificationManager NM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                            NM.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(),builder.build());
```

Comment: You can choose among three types of actions: start an Activity, start a Service or send a Broadcast. Your "function" has to be called by one of them.

Comment: Update: this one statement (plus the handful of lines to set up mDatabase) could be executed in a Service (or better an IntentService).